# Azure table storage Invalid input

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using Java to Query Azure table storage service.

I am querying a Azure table based on TimeStamp. Before executing query I converted the local java date to UTC.

Query is throwing an TableServiceException  "One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:59445f16-0002-007e-152d-b3e24d000000
Time:2016-05-21T06:50:34.5077574Z"

When I used same date and query data using Azure Storage explorer; I am able to get the desired value as shown in below screen shot.

http://puu.sh/oZD6y/eadcc45859.png This makes me wonder what am I doing wrong.

below is the code that I use to query Azure Table. endDate is of Type Date

```
String partitionFilter = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(PARTITION_KEY,   QueryComparisons.EQUAL,
            partitionKey);
    String date2 = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(TIMESTAMP, QueryComparisons.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, endDate.getTime());
    String finalFilter = TableQuery.combineFilters(partitionFilter, Operators.AND, date2);

    CloudTable table = getTable(tableName);
    TableQuery<TableServiceEntity> query = TableQuery.from(TableServiceEntity.class).where(finalFilter);
    Iterable<TableServiceEntity> tableEntries = table.execute(query);
    return tableEntries;
```

Below code is used to convert local date

```
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date localTime = new Date(ts);
    String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat (format);


    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.format(localTime));
    System.out.println("Local:" + localTime.toString() + "," + localTime.getTime() + " --> UTC time:" + gmtTime.toString() + "-" + gmtTime.getTime());
```

This already wasted my time a lot. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the value of `date2` variable? In fact, it would be much simpler if you show the value of `finalFilter`.

Comment: finalFilter value is (PartitionKey eq '1') and (Timestamp le 1463796341217L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (PartitionKey eq '1') and (Timestamp le 1463796341217L)

Basically you have an issue with your query. Essentially `Timestamp` is a `date/time` kind of attribute so if you were writing ODATA query yourself, your query should be something like:

```
(PartitionKey eq '1') and (Timestamp le datetime'some-date-time-value')
```

If you notice, this is something you're doing in Azure Storage Explorer as well.

Looking at your code, you are calling `getTime()` method on `endDate` which will return you milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. What you need to do is use `endDate` as is. Then the SDK will convert the query in the format understood by Azure Table Service.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time on this. I was actually trying it even after posting the question as well. What you said is right and that's how I tried later. The problem right now is my end date as in debugger show value as Sat May 21 08:55:17 IST 2016 but my date2 variable shows string as Timestamp le datetime'2016-05-21T03:25:17.000Z'. Please notice the time; it is some 3:25 Isn't this should be same as what is in my endDate i.e. 2016-05-21T08:55:17.000Z.  My final filter is (PartitionKey eq '1') and (Timestamp le datetime'2016-05-21T03:25:17.000Z')

Comment: ok I found out the solution. Actually I just have to pass local time,Azure table service converts it to UTC time and that's how comparison happens.